# Find End Date of month (Exclude Sunday and Saturday)

Tags: sql-server

I have wrote a script (from the internet) but it's not working because of some logical error I guess.

```
ALTER FUNCTION EstDateCheck (@CoustDesireddate varchar(10))
    RETURNS varchar(20) 
        AS
            BEGIN
                declare @testDate Date = (SELECT STUFF(@CoustDesireddate, 4, 0, '01/'));
                declare @lastWorkDay date = iif(DATEPART(WEEKDAY, EOMONTH(@testDate)) <= 5 
                                            ,EOMONTH(@testDate) 
                                            ,DATEADD(DAY, -(7-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, EOMONTH(@testDate))),EOMONTH(@testDate)))
                RETURN @lastWorkDay
            END
```

This is how I execute

```sql
select  dbo.EstDateCheck('07/2022')
```

Comment: What does "it's not working" mean? Are you getting an error? Unexpected results? Undesired behaviour? Something else..?

Comment: In truth, a calendar table would make this somewhat trivial.

Comment: hai. am getting output but its giving even sunday and saturday ending date

Answer (score 2):

I would, honestly, consider creating a calendar table. There are plenty of [examples](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Calendar+table+sql+server) out there, so I'm not going to cover how to create one; plus what columns you need vary.

What you will have, however, is a column to denote if the day is a weekday (and probably a working day), as well as what month and year it belongs to. As a result you can then simply get the last weekday with the following query:

```sql
SELECT MAX(CalendarDate)
FROM dbo.CalendarTable
WHERE CalendarYear = 2022
  AND CalendarMonth = 7
  AND Weekday = 1;
```

If you therefore wanted to do this as a function, you could use an inline table value function:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.MonthLastWeekday (@Year int, @Month int) 
RETURNS table
AS RETURN
    SELECT MAX(CalendarDate) AS LastWeekday
    FROM dbo.CalendarTable
    WHERE CalendarYear = @Year
      AND CalendarMonth = @Month
      AND Weekday = 1;
```

And then you would call the function as follows:

```sql
SELECT LastWeekday
FROM dbo.MonthLastWeekday(@Year,@Month);
```